# when i am importing a variable in index.js from app.js my getdata on click function showing error, i am trying to import variable from another file

Tags: javascript, events

Uncaught ReferenceError: getdata is not defined     at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:9:33)
i also try to use type = "module" but not working.
Pls suggest some way, i know it is beginer issue but i am also beginer So i am stuck for 2 days.
Inde.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <button onClick="getdata()">get data</button>

  <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="./app.js"></script>

  <!-- 
     <script  src="./index.js"></script>
     <script  src="./app.js"></script> 

   -->
 </body>
 </html>
```

index.js

```js
import data from './app.js';

function getdata(){

 console.log("hello");
 console.log(data);
}
```

app.js

```js
let data ="shiva"
export default data;
```

solution for importing another file variable in onclick function

Comment: You can only use `import` if the script is loaded with `type="module"`.

Comment: However, when you load a script as a module, its variables don't become global variables in the browser. You need to assign `window.getdata = getdata`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to import/export. you just need to add `app.js` script tag before the `index.js`.

Try this:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <button onClick="getdata()">get data</button>

  <script src="./app.js"></script>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```js
var data = "shiva"
```

index.js

```js
function getdata(){
 console.log("hello");
 console.log(data);
}
```